# How can I prevent the Legend from covering each Atlas Feature?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm generating an atlas with a set of polygons. I want the legend to be above the map, but to ensure that the legend doesn't actually cover the featured polygon. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example screenshot? Because I personally always place the legend beside the map, without any overlap.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting your legend outside the rectangle of the map?